# Prove using limit definition ($\varepsilon - \delta$)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\lim_{x\to p}$ $f(x) = L$. For convenience, assume $L>0$. Prove, using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ formalism, that $$\lim_{x\to p} [f(x)]^2 = L^2$$

My work:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow p} [f(x)]^2 = \lim_{x\to p}f(x) \cdot\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = L \cdot L = L^2$$

But that seems too easy, and doesn't involve $\varepsilon$ or $\delta$. Any other approaches? Please and thank you.

Comment: How do you prove that $\lim_{x \to p} f(x)g(x) = (\lim_{x \to p} f(x))(\lim_{x \to p} g(x))$? (When both limits exist.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a more appropriate phrasing for this question would be:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=L$. For convenience, assume $L>0$. Prove, using **the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit**, that 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow p}[f(x)]^2 = L^2
$$

We aren't just looking for some $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s to creep into your work any which way, we want you to unwrap the hypothesis and the desired result **with the definition of a limit**. So what is that definition?

$\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=L$ if and only if $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-p|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

We haven't proven it yet, but what would our result look like under this definition?

$\lim_{x\rightarrow p}[f(x)]^2=L^2$ if and only if $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-p|<\delta$ then $|f(x)^2-L^2|<\epsilon$.

Please note **that the $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s are different in these two definitions!**

The game is now to assume the first (since it is our hypothesis) and manipulate it until we get the second. If you need more of a hint, please comment and I will provide some more crumbs.

Comment: From limit definition, $|x-p|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<$ ${\epsilon}\over{|f(x)+L|}$. Now $|f(x)^2-L^2|=|(f(x)-L)(f(x)+L)|<|f(x)-L|\cdot|f(x)+L|<$ $\epsilon\over{|f(x)+L|}$ $\cdot|f(x)+L| = \epsilon$

Is this it?

Comment: Please see above, I need more of a hint, any crumbs will help.